# Add to cart is not working in fresh Magento

Tags: magento2, cart, error, products, shopping

I've installed Magento 2 fresh on localhost. trying add to cart items but it is not working when clicking on add to cart button. It shows You have no items in your shopping cart. Click here to continue shopping

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check your session and cookie settings. Sounds like the session cannot be started somehow. You could search for this here on Magento SE and try those things.

Comment: If your site URL is kind of localhost/Magento change it to 127.0.0.1/magento